# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: nondeterministic expressions are only allowed

Tags: apache-spark

I get an AnalysisException when I run the following query

```
spark.sql("select current_timestamp() as tsp, count(*) from table group by window(tsp, '5 minutes')")
```

I just want create a processing time column and want to run some simple stateful query like above. I understand current_timestamp is non deterministic and if so how can I add a processing time column and use group by to do a stateful aggregation?

I am using Spark 2.2.0